# Do I need to run precompile in production mode? Or is it done for me (Play framework 1.2.6)

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x, production, precompile

After noticing that, when started in prod mode, play pre-compiled the sources, I made the assumption that this was the equivalent of running "play precompile" and then starting play with -Dprecompiled=true. However, I've only just noticed that starting in prod mode does not create the "Precompiled" directory.

Therefore in my performance-dependent production environment where I don't care about picking up source code changes, should I be running precompile and then starting with precompiled=true even though it's already set to production mode?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

On my work we precompile the code first and start the app with -Dprecompile=true. In a local test Play precompile the code automatically if you start a play application in Production Mode with Start (play start --%prod). But i recommend you to precompile code first to know if there is a problem on the code (the app can have a problem and still start, without precompile the code).

You choose....